# Error displaying image preview before uploading

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, upload

I am using following code to upload image from multiple inputs and displaying a preview. I can view preview of first input only. When it comes to other three it does not work.

**SCRIPT**

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#blah')
      .attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah2" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah3" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah4" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
```

**NOTE:** Is there a way without changing HTML, and making some small change in script how to display preview.

I am using Bootstrap v3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do without changing the HTML. Using the [nextElementSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) you can get hold of the next element and assign the src value to it.

Alternetive is with jQuery's [.next()](https://api.jquery.com/next/) function that those the same thing.

```
$(input).next().attr('src', url);
```

I'm also suggesting using the [Object urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images) instead of reading the file as dataURL which takes time to compile and decompile back and forth between a base64 encoded string where as a object url is just a pointer to a file.

```
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(input.files[0]);
    input.nextElementSibling.src = url;
    // $(input).next().attr('src', url);
  }
}
```

If you could, maybe add a extra attribute to the file input `accept="image/*"` so they will only select a valid image file

Answer (score 1):

actually issue is that you use

```
$('#blah')
```

so every time you update only one image tag, you need to target the diff img tag accordingly, one way to do this is

**Html**

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this, 'blah');" />
 <img id="blah" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
 <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this, 'blah2');" />
 <img id="blah2" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
 <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this, 'blah3');" />
 <img id="blah3" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this, 'blah4');" />
  <img id="blah4" src="http://placehold.it/180" alt="your image" />
```

now you get diff id of img tag every time now you js function look like.

**JS**

```
function readURL(input, target) {
 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
 var reader = new FileReader();
 reader.onload = function (e) {
 $('#'+ target)
     .attr('src', e.target.result);
        };
         reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
        }
```

now it works, good luck

Comment: can you create a fiddle

Answer (score -1):

You need to add jQuery in your html file

```js
function readURL(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" onchange="readURL(this)"/>
<img src="#" id="blah" />
```